# Over-fitting text classification using random forest using R

Tags: r, text-mining, multiclass-classification

I have trained models and the accuracy of a trained model comes to `99.9%`. But when I fit model for test data accuracy is only `59.5%`.
I am working on text classification and using the random forest.

I have a few questions.

1. Can I accept this model?
2. Is this case of overfitting?
3. How can I get rid of overfitting?

confusionMatrix(PD3,train$Label )
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

```
      Reference
```

Prediction HIGH LOW MEDIUM
    HIGH    116   0      0
    LOW       0 120      1
    MEDIUM    0   1    233

Overall Statistics

```
           Accuracy : 0.9958          
             95% CI : (0.9847, 0.9995)
No Information Rate : 0.4968          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       

              Kappa : 0.9932
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA

Statistics by Class:

```
 Class: HIGH Class: LOW Class: MEDIUM

Sensitivity               1.0000     0.9917        0.9957
Specificity               1.0000     0.9971        0.9958
Pos Pred Value            1.0000     0.9917        0.9957
Neg Pred Value            1.0000     0.9971        0.9958
Prevalence                0.2463     0.2569        0.4968
Detection Rate            0.2463     0.2548        0.4947
Detection Prevalence      0.2463     0.2569        0.4968
Balanced Accuracy         1.0000     0.9944        0.9958
```

confusionMatrix(PD4,test$Label )
Confusion Matrix and Statistics Reference

```
Prediction HIGH LOW MEDIUM
    HIGH     24   0      5
    LOW       2  10     10
    MEDIUM   23  41     85
```

Overall Statistics

```
               Accuracy : 0.595           
                 95% CI : (0.5235, 0.6637)
    No Information Rate : 0.5             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.004361        

                  Kappa : 0.2818
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 4.28e-07

Statistics by Class:

```
                     Class: HIGH Class: LOW Class: MEDIUM
Sensitivity               0.4898     0.1961        0.8500
Specificity               0.9669     0.9195        0.3600
Pos Pred Value            0.8276     0.4545        0.5705
Neg Pred Value            0.8538     0.7697        0.7059
Prevalence                0.2450     0.2550        0.5000
Detection Rate            0.1200     0.0500        0.4250
Detection Prevalence      0.1450     0.1100        0.7450
Balanced Accuracy         0.7283     0.5578        0.6050
```

Comment: Yes, that is the typical case of overfitting. Random forest is a good way to perform a classification task, but it usually overfits when you have a high number of trees. Can you post how have you trained your RF model? See also this on how to choose the hyperparameters https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-machine-learning-algorithms-in-r/

Comment: Try to use cross validaton/bootstrap and varius mtry variables (the size of each tree), possibly lowering them and try reduce number of trees. You can use caret for that.

Comment: Hi, this is how I train my model after trying couple of  mtry and ntree tuning various hyperparameter its still overfit my model. any help please.'cv.folds <- createMultiFolds(train$Label,k = 10, times = 3)
cv.cntrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10,
                         repeats = 3,index = cv.folds,search="grid")

Comment: rf.cv.1 <- train(Label ~ ., data = train.tokens.tfidf.df, method = "rf", 
                 trControl = cv.cntrl, tuneLength = 10,na.action=na.exclude)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a clear example of overfitting

when working with text-classification it is usually good practice to apply massive data cleaning before applying any model as you have a huge number of variables. have you trim it, stem it and got rid go stop words?
moreover, I would suggest you to use cross-validation to select your model

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I did all preprocess pipeline to data. like 1:tokenization
#      2 - Lower casing
#      3 - Stopword removal
#      4 - Stemming
#      5 - Adding bigrams

Comment: did you apply tf-id and trimmed the DFM? it reduces the number of features before applying s classification task.

Comment: Hi Yes, I did trim the dfm something like this and then convert to TF-IDF aswell. but my random forest still overfit the model.  train.tokensb.dfm <- dfm_trim(train.tokens.dfm,min_termfreq =4, min_docfreq = 2)